# Calculating forces on cables

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mathematics, forces

I have to calculate the pull forces of Fab and Fac.
I have used extended Pythagoras to find the length of AC and AB but I have no idea how to calculate the forces. I also tried to use cartesian coordinates because I found a PFD with the same assignment somewhere on internet with the calculations but I don't understand it (https://people.utm.my/pauziahmuhamad/files/2018/12/Lecture_15.pdf).

Could someone help me with a solution preferably without the use of cartesian coordinates but with is ok, thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Won't the force be shared between the cables and you need the angle from the horizontal to the cable?

Comment: for A to not accelerate vertically, the vertical component of the sum of forces in the vertical direction must be zero.  W is 375N down so what do you need to cancel that out?

Comment: the answer is in breaking the diagonal forces to their x-y-z components.  People take statics to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the point vertically above O in the middle of B and C, D , the angle $AD$ makes with $AO$, $tetha$ , its force $F_{1}$ then it length
$$ L_{A D}=(0.6^2+0.2^2)^(1/2)=0.632m$$

And the length of AC,

$$L_{AC}=\sqrt{0.633^2+0.2^2}=0.663m$$
We get the moment aboutO.

$$\Sigma m_O=0 \quad \rightarrow 375*0.6= 0.3m*cos(F_1)$$

$$cos(F_1)=375(0.6/0.3)=750 $$

$$F_{AD}=750\frac{0.633}{0.6}=790N$$
This force, 790N is divided between the AB and AC.
$$790/2=395N$$

$$F_{AB}=F_{AC}=395\frac{0.663}{0.632}=414.73N$$

I used your figure to show the details.

.

[image: trss]

Comment: Thank you for the help and detailed explanation. But I think to calculate the Lad I have to use 0.6 and 0.3 instead of 0.6 and 0.2. Which would make it Lad=0.67m.

Comment: @daan, you are right. i just had momentary dyslexia!